# Can't connect to server's MySQL database from C#

Tags: c#, mysql

So before I jump into showing my code.

I'm still new to **C#**, **WPF** and **Windows App**. So I built an App for my company, the app will be installed on several computers in the office where all of these computers are connected to our local server network. It's on this server that the database for this app is stored and we use WAMP Server for the database.

When developing the app using **Visual Studio** and testing with the WAMP Server on my PC, everything worked fine. Now when I wanted to deploy the app, I changed the `server host` I used to connect to my database from `localhost` (which is pointing to my PC WAMP Server) to `192.168.10.1` (which is the IP Address of the company's server computer).

Now that's where the problem comes in. When the app is installed on the computers, it doesn't connect to the Server's database. I tried pinging the server (`ping 192.168.10.1`) and it was successful. I also tried accessing the database from other computers which are connected to the server computer by accessing a **PHP** API from the server computer and everything went well. So I was able to insert data into the database from browsers, for instance, accessing `http://192.168.10.1/insert-data.php`

For further debugging, I tried getting the error message from my **C#** code when connecting to the database

```
class DatabaseConnection
{
    private MySqlConnection conn;
    public string messageStr;

    public DatabaseConnection()
    {
        messageStr = "Hello";
        string connStr = "SERVER=192.168.10.1";
        connStr += ";DATABASE=myDatabase";
        connStr += ";UID=root";
        connStr += ";PASSWORD=;";
        using (conn = new MySqlConnection(connStr))
        {
            try
            {
                conn.Open();
            }
            catch (MySqlException ex)
            {
                messageStr = ex.Message;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Using the code this way:

```
DatabaseConnection dbConn = new DatabaseConnection();
MessageBox.Show(dbConn.messageStr);
```

When I tried running the app, this is the message I get

[image]

Then after some research, I was told to grant permission to the IP Address. So first, I editted my `httpd-vhost.conf` for the WAMP Server to this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName localhost
    DocumentRoot ${INSTALL_DIR}/www
    <Directory  "${INSTALL_DIR}/www/">
        Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

And also did this

```
CREATE USER 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'root';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'%';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

And when I try running the app again, this is what I get:

[image]

I don't know what else to do here, Please I need help

Comment: Having a program that's installed on a user's system connect directly to the database is a bad idea. In your case, it's especially bad because you're putting the *root user credentials* on each system and giving them full administrative access to the database. Even if you did have separate MySQL users for each person using the application, you still can't do row-level security, or prevent them from using another application to run queries that circumvent business logic. Build an API that the application can use to do its database operations.

Comment: It's good to see that security is a high priority for you. Hopefully, your not storing any valuable information (information that you wouldn't want to share with the world) in the database. Your issue can probably be resolved by setting a password and using that password. As someone else stated a new user should be created with only the necessary permissions, and obviously, a password.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I finally found a way out. For whatever reason which is unknown to me, I couldn't connect to `root` user, so I created a new user on the admin granting it all privileges.

And viola... It worked